# Neural Network learns better at high output values

Tags: neural-network

I'm training a feed forward neural network
(stochastic gradient descent, 3 small hidden layers, elu activation, inputs scaled between 0 and 1, weights initialized according to TiRune from
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229885/whats-the-recommended-weight-initialization-strategy-when-using-the-elu-activat)
on a function that outputs values from about 0 to 55.000. I'm satisfied with the result, it learns to approximate the function pretty well.
But when I scale the outputs to be between 0 and 1 (just outputs divided by 55.000) it stops learning pretty early, it performs much worse. I tried various learning rates, of course.

Is there a reason it learns much better when the output values are between 0 and 55.000 than when they are between 0 and 1? Or does it not make any sense and my problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the only difference between the networks is the output scaling (target scaling). For complete answer, I will give a list of possible reasons and include the learning rate you mentioned:

**How scaling the outputs can effect my learning?**

1. You may have a bug. If you scale the networks output, make sure you scale both `predictions` and `real outputs` that you feed during the training, validation and test.
2. Your output activation function cannot output at the target range. For instance, sigmoids can output values between `0` and `1`. Scaling output values between `0` and `10` will reduce performance since the targets cannot be produced.
3. Make sure you use correct data types. Normalization can be good, but if normalization causes loss of information due to data types, you should normalize to a larger range. Truncation and rounding errors will cause information loss.
4. Adjust the learning rate - normalization changes the derivatives values, and therefore the propagated gradients all the way to the updates.

Good luck!